# Access APEX without the context path /apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am using Oracle XE 18 with APEX 19.1 installed via EPG.

The only way to access the workspace login page is by locating the additional path `/apex`.

Is there a way to access/redirect/change the workspace login page (or a specific application) to the root of the hostname - such as `http://localhost` instead of `http://localhost/apex` ?

PS.: I am using Windows

Comment: If you use a browser which supports a toolbar (such as Mozilla Firefox), create a *shortcut button* and access the login page in one click (and avoid typing "http://localhost"). As of your question: I wouldn't know.

Answer (score 2):

The out of the box answer is: no
With APEX you need that, it can be changed to something like /app  or similar.

If it was a deal breaker you can always front that APEX with a proxy that forwards the calls, one that comes to mind is nginx but its not perfect, something like an F5-like device can do the redirection pretty smoothly.

For Windows in particular you can try the DNS service which allows you to define some forwarding rules but I sincerely don't know how far you can go with this approach.

I suggest you choose /a or similar  (instead of /apex)  and save yourself a ton of problems and headaches. What you want doesn't exist, it was not designed to do that.

Comment: thanks for the answer. any suggestions on how to make this work on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is possible but to do this you need a network layer,  a network layer can be a firewall or web server(apache/glassfish).  So in my case i use glassfish. You can specify redirect properties on glassfish config file domain.xml like this:

```
 <virtual-server network-listeners="http-listener-1" id="server">
   <property name="redirect_1" value="from= url-prefix=/apex/"></property>
   <property name="redirect_2" value="from=/my_app_name url-prefix=/apex/f?p=my_number_app"></property>
          
</virtual-server>
```

So the first property as the rule you need to redirect /apex  to /.
The second property you can use to redirect any application to a route name.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this answer? It's very unclear.

Comment: Hi,  i update the answer